# SSRS Rows Grouping Customization and Sum

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have four columns in my report, whom title I'm changing basses on parameters. Now I want to remove grouping, if the parameter value is false. toggles the grouping( remove grouping / add grouping) on column.
I'm using rows Group for applying groupng

Comment: Usually you add both the detail and the grouping then hide one or the other based on the parameter

Comment: binding time of report will be increased in this case

Comment: I solved this by creating separate reports, for instance I could not find any appropriate solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating separate reports, for instance I could not find any appropriate solution for this problem